# Cakephp 2 get controller and action from $this->referer()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePhp 2.5, how can i get the controller and action using  `$this->referer()`, without having to use php explode function.

```
(int) 0 => 'http:',
(int) 1 => '',
(int) 2 => 'localhost',
(int) 3 => 'mysite',
(int) 6 => 'books',
(int) 7 => 'list'
```

My goal is to use the same code in production and in my local development.

If i do use explode the indexes from local can be diferent from production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CakeRoute::parse($url)` method to reverse a string into an array.

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#CakeRoute::parse

```
$url = CakeRoute::parse($this->referer());
```